# why subfigure doesn't occupy the full textwidth

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have 5 subfigures with width set to be `0.2 \textwidth`, I want them to be in one row, but I have to set their width smaller than 0.2 to do that.
Does anyone know the reason? 
Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome, you might have spaces in between them. But it is really hard to tell, without any code. Can you present a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/)?

Comment: With standard paper and margins, you only have 6.5in of textwidth. So you have have `6.5/5 - 4*(gap distance desired)` between each picture for the max width of each picture or some calculation of this nature to determine max size. You can adjust the margins with the `geometry`.

Comment: Which package do you use to create subfigures: `subfigure` (obsolete/deprecated), `subfig`, or `subcaption`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't state which package you use to help create the `subfigure` environments: `subfigure` -- which is deprecated and ought not to be used anymore -- `subfig`, or `subcaption`. I'll assume you're using `subcaption`.

One needs to remember that TeX converts single line breaks into space tokens. Thus, if each `subfigure` environment is terminated with a newline directive, the total width is 5*0.2\textwidth + 4*(width of space token), which exceeds `\textwidth`.

You have two choices: insert a `%` (comment character) at the end of the first four `subfigure` environments (to suppress the implicit insertion of a space character) or choose a width for each `subfigure` that's slightly less than `0.2\textwidth`. I actually prefer the second approach.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}  
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\hrule  %% just to illustrate width of text block

%% Five subfigures, width 0.2\textwidth, 
%% use "%" to assure no gap,
%% set image widths to 0.95\textwidth
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{figa}
\caption{First}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{figb}
\caption{Second}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{figc}
\caption{Third}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{figd}
\caption{Fourth}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{fige}
\caption{Fifth}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

%% Five subfigures, width 0.18\textwidth, 
%% use "\hspace{\fill}" to maximize gaps,
%% set image widths to 1\textwidth
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{subfigure}{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figa}
\caption{First}
\end{subfigure}\hspace{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figb}
\caption{Second}
\end{subfigure}\hspace{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figc}
\caption{Third}
\end{subfigure}\hspace{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figd}
\caption{Fourth}
\end{subfigure}\hspace{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{fige}
\caption{Fifth}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing! I was thinking that there is something in between.